# How to add a function in return in statement using typescript , when I add function to convert the date I am getting , is not a funtion error

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax-error

I am new to scripting, How to add a function in return in statement using typescript , when I try to add function toLocaleString() or formatDate(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en') when returning to export excel sheet to convert the date I am getting  'is not a funtion error'..

How to formate date and what is the syntax , where I can add the condition in this case.

Please ignore other syntax of the code, please help to add a function to format effectiveDate

Thank you

```js
 let expList: Array<IRuleForm> = [];

    let headers: string[] = [
      'Form Sub-Type',
      'Effective Date',
      'Transaction'
      ];


expList = expList.map(function(item) {
      item['Form_Sub-Type'] = item['formSubType'];
      item['Effective_Date'] = item['effectiveDate'];
      item['Transaction_Type'] =        item['assignedTransactions'];
      
     return item;
    });

addToExportList(
    entry: IRuleForm
    )
       return {
        col1: entry.formSubType,
        col2: entry.effectiveDate.toLocaleDateString(),
        co3: entry.assignedTransactions
        .map((x) => {
          return x.transactionType;
        }).join(', ')
      }
```

Comment: What is `expList`?

Comment: You shared very small part of code which i can see some syntax errors but not sure until you can tell me what is before and after this section

Comment: Please ignore other syntax of the code and can you please help to add a function to format effectiveDate